# Block Computer Permanently Networking

Tags: java, security, networking, block, netty

I want to block a user from my game server; what would be a guaranteed way in which most people don't know to change? IP Addresses can be easily changed and MAC Addresses can be spoofed. This is being done in Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to block an individual person. You can block login IDs and IP addresses but as you already know that won't prevent an individual from using a different login or a computer on a different IP.  Plus, if the user is connecting from behind a NAT firewall you will be blocking ALL users coming from behind that firewall.

You could set up a registration system that involved you personally verifying every user's identity (not sure how you'd accomplish that with anything close to 100% accuracy) but that would just put obstacles in the way of your legitimate users.

You can't win this battle.

Comment: No, you can't win it. But you can make it expensive for the bad player.

Comment: Despite its flaws, I would still go with blocking an IP and blocking an account, because:  (1) It would indeed make it expensive for offending players (most people don't know how to change their IP or spoof packets).  (2) Partially effective is better than nothing.  (3) The firewall issue is certainly true, but the nature of vandalism is that people who are blameless always end up paying for it somehow.